# Symmetric solutions of matrix equation $X-AXB=C$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Consider the matrix equation for unknown matrix $X$

$$X-AXB=C$$

where $A,B,C$ are symmetric $n\times n$ matrices (can be definite, semidefinite, or indefinite). It is well known that a solution $X$ exists if and only if

$$\mbox{rank} (I_{n^2}-A \otimes B^{T}) = \mbox{rank} ([I_{n^2}-A \otimes B^{T},vec(C)])$$

where $I_{n^2}$ is the identity matrix of size $n^2 \times n^2$.

However, my question is whether someone knows of a necessary and sufficient condition for the equation above to have a **symmetric** solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It should be $I-B^T\otimes A$, not $I-A\otimes B^T$. To impose a symmetry condition, just rewrite $X=X^T$ as $(I-K)\operatorname{vec}(X)=0$, where $K$ is the [commutation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix). Now your system of linear equations becomes
$$
\pmatrix{I-B^T\otimes A\\ I-K}\operatorname{vec}(X)=\pmatrix{\operatorname{vec}(C)\\ 0}
$$
and hence a solution exists if and only if
$$
\operatorname{rank}\pmatrix{I-B^T\otimes A\\ I-K}
=\operatorname{rank}\pmatrix{I-B^T\otimes A&\operatorname{vec}(C)\\ I-K&0}.
$$

Comment: @ user1551 , if you stack the matrix row by row, then the considered  function is $I-A\otimes B^T$. I use this convention.